# Why can't I import classes from a dependency that exists in the parent POM?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I am a beginner in Spring. In my project, the `pom.xml` defines the parent as `spring-boot-starter-parent`, and I see that the parent of `spring-boot-starter-parent` is `spring-boot-dependencies`. The `spring-boot-dependencies` already has the `lombok` dependency, but I am unable to import it in my project.
I'm not sure if my understanding of the parent's role is correct. I hope someone can help clarify this.

Thank you.

mypom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    .............
</project>
```

spring-boot-starter-parent-3.1.2.pom

```
   ..............
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
  </parent>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>spring-boot-starter-parent</name>
  <description>Parent pom providing dependency and plugin management for applications built with Maven</description>
  ..........
```

spring-boot-dependencies-3.1.2.pom

```
.............line 1306
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      </dependency>
.............
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check **spring-boot-starter-parent** pom file you will see it also has a parent pom file named **spring-boot-dependencies**. In spring-boot-dependencies.pom, dependencies are declared inside **dependencyManagement** section, which means when you set spring-boot-starter-parent as your parent pom, you inherit the versions of the dependencies declared in  dependency-management part but not the dependencies. So when you add lombok dependency to your project without a version, it will provide the same version that spring-boot manages. If you inherited all the dependencies declared in a parent pom, you would have huge jar files with so many dependencies which are not needed.

I hope it helps,

Comment: So you should just add lombok dependency to your project's pom file.

Comment: Indeed, I've noticed that the packages within `spring-boot-dependencies` are declared within `dependencyManagement`. This is different from declaring them directly within `dependencies`.Thank you so much.